# How do you retrieve notification detail into individual data elements with swift 3

Tags: swift, push-notification

I'm trying to read all received notifications for an app and load them in a collection view.  Would like to be able to retrieve the title, body ... individually.  My count is returning OK but content.body and content.title are blank. Can return notification.description but is full string.  Do I have to manually parse the description?

Thanks for any assistance

```
//read all existing notifications

func listNotification() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications(
        completionHandler: {receivedNotifications -> () in

        print("Received notification #\(receivedNotifications.count)")

        for notification in receivedNotifications {
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            print(" Body \(content.body)")
            print(" Title \(content.title)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the contents of the constant `content`, however you haven't initialised it using the `notification` you are iterating, nowhere in your code this variable is read.

```
for notification in receivedNotifications {
        let content = notification.request.content
        print(" Body \(content.body)")
        print(" Title \(content.title)")
}
```

Try it this way.

`getDeliveredNotifications` returns an array of [UNNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/UNNotification), where each has a request ([UNNotificationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/UNNotificationRequest)) and within an instance of [UNNotificationContent](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/UNNotificationContent):

> var title: String
>
> var subtitle: String
>
> var body: String
>
> var badge: NSNumber?
>
> var sound: UNNotificationSound?
>
> var launchImageName: String
>
> var userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]
>
> var attachments: [UNNotificationAttachment]